# How to modify an identified noun phrase A to B or C--->A to B or A to C in Spacy, Regular Expression python

Tags: python, regex, nltk, spacy

I have identified the noun phrase A to B or C by using spaCy rule-based matcher. However, I want to modify the obtained result:

```
A to B or C--->A to B or A to C
```

And make sure that the original meaning is correct.

How can I do this in python by using regular expression + spacy or nltk or anything else is helpful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `re.sub` as follows:

```py
inp = "A to B or C"
output = re.sub(r'\b(\S+) to (\S+) or (\S+)\b', r'\1 to \2 or \1 to \3', inp)
print(output)  # A to B or A to C
```

Comment: Thanks, why didn't I get any output by just entering these three lines plus "import re" into an IDE?

Comment: @Nina No idea, I ran my code in a demo tool and it worked.